# Get APNS payload contents while selecting the received push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am receiving a list of push notification. If user selects a notification I want to get the data from that selected notification.from the list of notifications

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have posted my code please share your thoughts

Comment: @GeneCode I have posted my code please share your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
NSLog(@"Notification Received .. Dictionary %@",userInfo);
NSString *user_TYP = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"User_TYPE_LOG"];
NSLog(@"Usr type == %@",user_TYP);
if ([user_TYP isEqualToString:@"type1"])
    {
        //        VW_User_NOTific *VW_SER = [[VW_User_NOTific alloc]initWithNibName:@"VW_User_NOTific" bundle:nil];
        VW_User_NOTific *listingVC = [[VW_User_NOTific alloc] init];
        [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:listingVC animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        VW_JS_Notific *listingVC = [[VW_JS_Notific alloc] init];
        [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:listingVC animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**for Swift**: The notification data is delivered to your app in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. 
If you want to process it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` you should store it in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and read it again in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

when your app is in foreground in application`:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` you can query `UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState` to find out if your app is already in the foreground. If it is then just process the notification right away.

if app is launched via push notification you can also check push data in

```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
          // app was launched from push notification, handling it
    let remoteNotification: NSDictionary! = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary
    if (remoteNotification != nil) {

    }
}
```

**for Objective C**: to query app state 
you can query `-[UIApplication applicationState]` to find out if your app is already in the foreground and when app is launched from push use:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Check for options
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        //Store the data from the push.
        dUserInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dUserInfo != nil)
        {
            //Do whatever you need
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this

Comment: Great thanks this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Notification Received .. Dictionary %@",userInfo);
    NSString *user_TYP = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"User_TYPE_LOG"];
    NSLog(@"Usr type == %@",user_TYP);

    // all the data required is present in your info dictionary

    id data1 = userInfo[@"key1"]; // user your data_type instead of id
    id data2 = userInfo[@"key2"];

    if(received data == x && [user_TYP isEqualToString:@"type1"])
       do_something;
    else
       do_something_else;

}
```

Comment: it does not works in ios 10

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It is working